# Cannot connect to MySQL Database with Cron job

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, cron

I'm trying to make a cron job to delete any users that have deactivated their accounts a year ago, the script works on the website but when doing it through a cron job, I get a fatal error.

`Fatal error:  Cannot instantiate non-existent class: pdo in /homepages/9/d526231279/htdocs/cupidmemories/cronjobs/users.cron.php on line 2`

Here is my **users.cron.php** file:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=dbhost.com:port; dbname=dbname;', 'user', 'pass');

$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE account_deleted='4'";
$db->query($query);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Fatal error: Cannot instantiate non-existent class* error message was shown by [good old PHP/4](https://3v4l.org/5FaG4). The [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) class requires PHP/5.1.0 or greater. You simply cannot use such an outdated interpreter to run anything that resembles modern code.

Hopefully, your hosting provider might have a newer interpreter available if you provide the appropriate full path, so you could replace this:

```
*/10 * * * * php /homepages/9/d526231279/htdocs/cupidmemories/cronjobs/users.cron.php
```

... with e.g. this:

```
*/10 * * * * /opt/php5.6/bin/php /homepages/9/d526231279/htdocs/cupidmemories/cronjobs/users.cron.php
```

(These are fake paths, don't just copy them expecting to work.)

Answer (score 1):

Most Apache/PHP installations have 2 seperate `php.ini` files.

I would say that the one used by Apache/PHP is fine, but the other one does not have the PDO extension activated.

Do a

```
>php --ini
```

from the command line and you will see line which tells you where PHP CLI got its `php.ini` file from. Edit that so that the

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.so
```

is activated